# Add link around image in wysihtml5 editor

Tags: php, jquery, html, wysihtml5

I was wondering how I can make

`<img alt="" src="img.jpg">` //added from wysihtml5 with the standard command `insertImage`

into:

`<a href="img.jpg"><img alt="" src="img.jpg"></a>`

Preferably I'd like to do this in wysihtml5, but I'm assuming PHP is also possible? So how can I do this?

Help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:** I'd like to add that I did Google this. I didn't find anything for wysihtml5 but I did find something for PHP:

`preg_replace('#(<img[^>]+ src="([^"]*)" alt="[^"]*" />)#', '<a href="$2" ...>$1</a>', $str)`

But that didn't work.